# Recursive loop to create a family tree? (PHP/MySQL/HTML)

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, loops

Currently creating my own breeding website, but I am struggling with retrieving, processing and showing the pedigree of a given dog. I can do it if I pretty much hard-code it but not dynamically by retrieving parents (and parents of parents, etc...) until parents aren't found anymore.

MYSQL is basic:

**tbl_dogs** (table)
 - dog_id
 - dog_name
 - dog_sex
 - mother_id
 - father_id

The idea is to retrieve parents of one dogs, then parents of each dog in the tree, until mother_id/father_id aren't specified.

I am completely lost, so far I have been doing it the hard-coded way:

```
    $mother["id"] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_mother_id", true);
    $mother["name"] = get_animal_name($mother["id"]);
    $mother["permalink"] = get_the_permalink($mother["id"]);

        $mother_mother["id"] = get_mother_id($mother["id"]);
        $mother_mother["name"] = get_animal_name($mother_mother["id"]);
        $mother_mother["permalink"] = get_the_permalink($mother_mother["id"]);

        $mother_father["id"] = get_father_id($mother["id"]);
        $mother_father["name"] = get_animal_name($mother_father["id"]);
        $mother_father["permalink"] = get_the_permalink($mother_father["id"]);

    $father["id"] = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "_father_id", true);
    $father["name"] = get_animal_name($father["id"]);
    $father["permalink"] = get_the_permalink($father["id"]);

        $father_mother["id"] = get_mother_id($father["id"]);
        $father_mother["name"] = get_animal_name($father_mother["id"]);
        $father_mother["permalink"] = get_the_permalink($father_mother["id"]);

        $father_father["id"] = get_father_id($father["id"]);
        $father_father["name"] = get_animal_name($father_father["id"]);
        $father_father["permalink"] = get_the_permalink($father_father["id"]);
```

And I then would just use my family tree HTML5 structure to display this data.

```
<div class="pedigree-tree">
  <ul>
    <li><span><a href="<?php echo $mother["permalink"] ?>"><?php echo $mother["name"]; ?></a></span>
      <ul>
        <li><span><a href="<?php echo $mother_mother["permalink"] ?>"><?php echo $mother_mother["name"] ?></a></span>
          <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Grand-Grandmother</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span><a href="<?php echo $mother_mother["permalink"] ?>"><?php echo $mother_mother["name"] ?></a></span></li>
                    <li><span><a href="<?php echo $mother_mother["permalink"] ?>"><?php echo $mother_mother["name"] ?></a></span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span>Grand-Grandfather</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span><a href="<?php echo $mother_father["permalink"] ?>"><?php echo $mother_father["name"] ?></a></span>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Entry-1-2-1</span></li>
            <li><span>Entry-1-2-1</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span><a href="<?php echo $father["permalink"] ?>"><?php echo $father["name"]; ?></a></span>
      <ul>
        <li><span><a href="<?php echo $father_mother["permalink"] ?>"><?php echo $father_mother["name"] ?></a></span>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Entry-1-1-1</span></li>
            <li><span>Entry-1-1-1</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span><a href="<?php echo $father_father["permalink"] ?>"><?php echo $father_father["name"] ?></a></span>
          <ul>
            <li><span>Entry-1-2-1</span></li>
            <li><span>Entry-1-2-1</span></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But this solution, although working, is not at all suited to my needs since it is not flexible at all. I want to build a function that will go through as many generations as I will ask for (if they exist) and put that into an Array that I will then output through nested HTML lists as done above.

This "logical loop" to retrieve all parents is driving me insane, any help would be appreciated.. Thanks a million!

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that big deal. So basically you check if a dog has a mother and/or a father and execute the function again for each dog.

```
$stmnt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT dog_id, dog_name, dog_sex, mother_id, father_id
    FROM tbl_dogs
    WHERE dog_id = ?
");

fetchDogRecursive($yourDogId);

function fetchDogRecursive($dogId)
{
    $stmnt->execute(array($dogId));

    $dogData = $stmnt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0];

    $dog = array(
        'id' => $dogData['dog_id'],
        'name' => $dogData['dog_name'],
        'mother' => null,
        'father' => null
    );

    if($dogData['mother_id'] !== null) {
        $dog['mother'] = fetchDogRecursive($dogData['mother_id']);
    }

    if($dogData['father_id'] !== null) {
        $dog['father'] = fetchDogRecursive($dogData['father_id']);
    }

    return $dog;
}
```

Comment: this has *solved* my problematic, just had to adapt the code to my actual source and database (wordpress) but it works amazingly well. I added a generation value to each dog so I know which generation they belong to, just going to write the HTML output code (using nested UL, LI)

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea is like this:

```
function getDog ($id)
{
    // do your lookup

    if (isset($dog->father_id) && !empty($dog->father_id)) {
        $dog->father = getDog($dog->father_id);
    }

    if (isset($dog->mother_id) && !empty($dog->mother_id)) {
        $dog->mother = getDog($dog->mother_id);
    }

    return $dog;
}
```

It's not pretty, and you'll need to add logic to find the appropriate ancestor names, but you could get a dog's grandfather using `getDog(123)->father->father`

Answer (score -1):

Another starting point for a possible solution:

```
function tree($motherId) {

    $tree = array();

    while ($motherId <> 0) :

        $sqlToGetMother = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dogs WHERE mother_id = ".$motherId;

       // run the query.....

       $motherId = "dog_id from the query above";
       $motherName = "dog_name from the query above";

       $tree[] = $motherName;

    endwhile;

    // if you need to reverse the family tree
    krsort($tree);

    return $tree;
}


// Starts with a given dog_id....
tree($dog_id);
```

Is up to you to secure sql code, you can repeat the function for the fathers' tree or combine mothers and fathers in the same function.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it should not be up to the reader to have to secure the SQL used in your example. Use secure methods (such as prepared statements) in your examples otherwise this will just lead to people blindly copy/pasting your code without understanding what is wrong.

Comment: You are right about prepared statements in an absolute way but I cannot agree with you in this case: I think the point here is the recursion and not sql security or giving the user a "copy / paste ready snippet" (my answer is only a hint to start from) So I think your downvote is not that right...

Comment: @Phylogenesis people who blindly copy code from somewhere without understandig it and without even testing it don't write solid/secure code anyway ;-).